# OutOfMemory error for Java SSL server on SunOS

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, out-of-memory

I'm having issues with an SSL on Jetty; after a new cert install, OutOfMemory errors on startup, eg.

```
Exception in thread "btpool0-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:59)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.<init>(OutputRecord.java:56)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.<init>(OutputRecord.java:66)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.<init>(AppOutputStream.java:33)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:514)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:428)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledSuites(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:284)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:253)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector.accept(SslSocketConnector.java:169)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:514)
        at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Not even sure where to start - certificate exports back out of the keystore and we can -printcert on it, seem to be fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is jvm startup memory and certificate size? It seems you are running jvm with very less memory. Check -Xms and -Xmx parameters

Comment: Did you read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623676/suns-java-ssl-implementation-is-leaking-memory) though yours occurs on startup. Did you have a chance to test on another OS?

Comment: @thinksteep Tried with -Xmx large heaps up to 1G. No difference.

Comment: @BGR No other OS, was working fine on this system with old certificate that was due to expire. What kinds of things about a new certificate to cause this kind of problem I guess?

Comment: Key size (1024 vs 2048) ? SSLv3 Extensions (don't see why but could be a bug in the SunOS JVM).